# Is there a way to delete something off your computer but not your itunes account?

Tags: itunes, mac, music, accounts, macos

Memory on my computer is running low. Is there a way to remove stuff from my iTunes account (like delete them from my computer) and still have them on my account (not delete them off my account) so that I can access them on another computer?

Comment: What do you mean with "iTunes Account"?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

Easiest, but most costly is to subscribe to iTunes Match service which will let you download your entire library on another device and keep it in the cloud for you.

Harder, but relatively cheaper is to migrate your iTunes library to another computer.

[Migrating iTunes library when replacing the hard disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17693/migrating-itunes-library-when-replacing-the-hard-disk)

Middle-ground is to enable home sharing which is a simple way to transfer.

[transferring itunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/transferring-itunes)

Then afterwards delete songs from old comp. easiest thing to do for that is delete it from iTunes and agree to also remove the file and remove from library (on this computer). Old files will be in the trash bin until you empty it.